# Issues with Dapper query syntax

Tags: c#, sql, .net, oracle, dapper

little assistance here with my query using dapper, been getting error Message = "ORA-00936: missing expression\n" on my query. I would like to know what am I missing here?

```
  public class LocationDto
        {
            public int LocationId { get; set; }
            public int RouteId { get; set; }
            public string StartTime { get; set; }
            public string Location { get; set; }
        }
// Query Below
    using (OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString))
                {
     try {
                        var x = connection.QueryAsync<LocationDto>("Select ROUTE_ID as RouteId,  SCHEDULE_STOP as Location, START_TIME as StartTime From SCHEDULE WHERE ROUTE_ID = @Id", new { input.RouteId }).Result.ToList();
    
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    { 
                    
                    }
    }
```

Comment: Try renaming `@Id` to `@RouteId` and see what happens.

Comment: @ADyson, its just refusing for both attempts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly with Oracle queries you need to use `:` instead of `@` to denote a parameter placeholder.

Then secondly this code:

```
new { input.RouteId }
```

will produce an object with a property called `RouteId`.

This `RouteId` does not match the name of the parameter in your query, which is `Id`. They need to match, otherwise there's no way for the database to bind the parameter to the correct input value.

You can either

1. change the Sql query:

   ```
   WHERE ROUTE_ID = :RouteId
   ```

OR

2. change the C#:

   ```
   new { Id = input.RouteId }
   ```

and use `:Id` in the SQL.

It doesn't really matter which, the important thing is that the names match.

Comment: Nop!!, is it maybe because its oracle query or it don't matter?

Comment: What does "Nop" mean exactly? Are you still getting the same error, or a different one? Please always be specific when describing a problem, otherwise it's hard to be sure exactly what's going on or how to help.

Comment: Nop means no i was still getting the same error, But issue is sorted, had to use : instead of @. like this  WHERE ROUTE_ID = :RouteId

Comment: Ah ok. yes other Oracle Dapper examples show using `:`. But not all seem to, so I wasn't entirely sure if it was needed (I don't use oracle these days). I will amend the answer anyhow, as it sounds like you needed my changes as well as the `:`. Then you will be able to mark this accepted / upvote it as a complete answer.

Comment: yeah sure, you can amend